# pandas how to convert a dataframe to a matrix using transpose

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
code    y_m        count
101     2017-11    86
101     2017-12    32
102     2017-11    11
102     2017-12    34
102     2018-01    46
103     2017-11    56
103     2017-12    89
```

now I want to convert this `df` into a matrix that transposes column `y_m` to row, make the `count` as matrix cell values like,

```
     0     1     2             3             4 
 0   -1    0    2017-11       2017-12       2018-01
 1   0    354   153           155           46
 2   101  118   86            32            -1
 3   102   91   11            34            46
 4   103  145   -1            89            -1
```

in specific, `-1` represents a dummy value that indicates either a value doesn't exist for a `y_m` for a specific `code` or to maintain matrix shape; `0` represents 'all' values, that aggregates `code` or `y_m` or `code` and `y_m`, e.g. cell `(1, 1)` sums the `count` values for all `y_m` and `code`; `(1,2)` sums the `count` for `2017-11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='code',
                      columns='y_m',
                      values='count', 
                      margins=True, 
                      aggfunc='sum', 
                      fill_value=-1, 
                      margins_name='0'))
print (df1)
y_m   2017-11  2017-12  2018-01    0
code                                
101        86       32       -1  118
102        11       34       46   91
103        56       89       -1  145
0         153      155       46  354
```

And then for final format, but get mixed values, numeric with strings:

```
#change order of index and columns values for reindex
idx = df1.index[-1:].tolist() + df1.index[:-1].tolist()
cols = df1.columns[-1:].tolist() + df1.columns[:-1].tolist()

df2 = (df1.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'code':-1})
         .rename_axis(None,1))
#add columns to first row
df3 = df2.columns.to_frame().T.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)
#reset columns names to range
df3.columns = range(len(df3.columns))
print (df3)
     0    1        2        3        4
0   -1    0  2017-11  2017-12  2018-01
1    0  354      153      155       46
2  101  118       86       32       -1
3  102   91       11       34       46
4  103  145       56       89       -1
```